# How to count how many bars back when closing price crossed and close above certain moving average to known swing low and swing high?

Tags: mql4

I need to get dynamic bar count using moving average to find swing low and swing high. Please check screenshot for better understanding Thanks in advance
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rv4uH.jpg

```
   double mafast = iMA(NULL,0,15,0,MODE_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,1);
   double maslow = iMA(NULL,0,30,0,MODE_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,1);
   int i=1;
  for (i = 1; i<=Bars; i++) 
    { 
      if (mafast<maslow || mafast>maslow);

      }
      int low = iLowest(NULL,0,MODE_LOW,i-1,0);
      int high =iHighest(NULL,0,MODE_HIGH,i-1,0);

     Print(Low[low]);
     Print(High[high]);

     }
```

actual 'Bars' function is getting value for entire chart but i need that should be quantify based on Moving Average price close above or below with strong move

Comment: I am unsure of what you are after... Do you want to loop back through the Bars to find the most recent swing high/low before the crossing of the MA?

Comment: Also, in your code you have `if(mafast<maslow || mafast>maslow);`. This should almost always evaluate to true because of the nature of the structure. Do you not want to break this into separate arguments so you can look at when there is a cross up, look for swing low, and if there is a cross down, look for swing high?

Comment: Thanks for kind response @Dean yes i need to find recent high/low before the crossing of the MA but only after crossing and closed above MA please check the link for further clarification my humble request imgur.com/IwxEzeQ